# image paths not right when deploying .war on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war

After developing a Java web project, I used maven to create a war package, which I later deployed on Tomcat. My deployment was done by uploading the war file to the webapps folder in tomcat. When I restart the Tomcat server, however, I found the image path and css/js file paths are not right. I am a newbie to Tomcat thing, and I've tried to read some online help/documents but found not much helpful answer.

I named my war file to admin.war, and a new folder named 'admin' was created after Tomcat restarted. So I access my web app using `localhost:8080/admin`

I use the Ninja framework for developing my web app, and the following is the content of my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0"
         metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>ninja</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>ninja.servlet.NinjaServletListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

In my templates (Freemarker), I have the following urls for serving static files, as I understand, it's absolute path, which might be the reason for my problem with Tomcat(?)

```
<link href="/assets/admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use ${contextPath} like so:

```
<link href="${contextPath}/assets/admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will add "admin" to your path in your case automatically.

More here:
http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/html_templating/advanced_topics.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying as `admin.war` then you need to make your assets path to `/admin/assets/...`.